# Is HttpWebRequest implemented differently in mono and .net?

Tags: c#, mono, stream, httpwebrequest, cloudinary

I am trying to port the c# cloudinary api to mono and I am having some problems building up the http request.

I have separated out this method for setting up the request but the HttpWebRequest.ContentLength turns out to be -1 in mono, but is .net the content is properly built.

I am running the newest Xamarin Studio on a Mac and I am building a MONO / .NET 4.0 library
Mono version: 2.10.12

EDIT: Simplified code, this test passes in Visual Studio but fails in Xamarin studio

EDIT: Code is pushed to [github](https://github.com/terjetyl/CloudinaryMono) if anybody would like to help

```
    [Test]
    public void StreamTest()
    {
        var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foo.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write("anything");
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(request.ContentLength > 0);
    }
```

Comment: What version of Mono are you running?

Comment: I am building a MONO/.net 4.0 library. Newest Xamarin Studio

Comment: Can you check the *exact* version of Mono you're using. You can find out by running "mono -version" on the command line.

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.12 (mono-2-10/c9b270d Thu Mar  7 21:38:12 EST 2013)

Comment: `ContentLength` is not a property of *Stream* but *HttpWebRequest*. The implementation differences might be in *HttpWebRequest*.

Comment: Why do you need to check Request.ContentLenght? Because probably ContentLenght is calculated only when the request is started, so I think when GetResponse is called. The HTTP header can be set and so maybe ContentLenght is only calculated in this phase? If you need to known the ContentLength maybe you can first calculate it manually (for example using Encoding.GetBytes).

Comment: I've had a similar issue with the HttpListener in Mono, there was a bug with DateTime.Now always returning 0 on ARM platforms. This was fixed in later versions of Mono. Version 2.10 is somewhat old and there have been many changes since then, you might have much better luck with a more recent version.

Comment: @terjetyl ,  Hi, Were you able to fix it? I am currently working on porting for Mono-droid.  Facing issues were same code run on desktop works but fails in xamarin. The tests in VS passes.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foo.com");
```

you actually create an instance of the internal class [System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.Net.Browser/BrowserHttpWebRequest.cs)

Here is the inheritance hierarchy

[System.Net.WebRequest](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net/System.Net/WebRequest_2_1.cs)
  [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net/System.Net/HttpWebRequest_2_1.cs)
    [System.Net.Browser.PolicyBasedWebRequest](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.Net.Browser/PolicyBasedHttpWebRequest.cs)
      [System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.Net.Browser/BrowserHttpWebRequest.cs)

The content length is handled in PolicyBasedWebRequest, initialized in ctor with -1 and never changed; 
I suggest you manually set it.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19547/parse-push-rest-api-error-400-bad-request)

It suggests that replacing this:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(bundleString);
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
requestWriter.Flush();
requestWriter.Close();
```

with this:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bundleString.Length;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(bundleString);
requestWriter.Flush();
requestWriter.Close();
```

fixed the problem. You can try this.